# Allergic to grapes, apple and cherry how to use recipes with wine

Tags: substitutions, wine

Wine allergy is my problem... not alcohol. I am also allergic to grapes, apples and cherries. Many recipes call for wine... what can I substitute?

Comment: if not rice then perhaps mirin

Comment: Hello Gail, the answers in the other question cover a lot of ingredients which are not triggered by the allergies you listed, so I'm closing it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the flavor without the classic source of the flavor, the fruit would seem difficult for an exact match.  For alcohol content a relatively neutral tasting vodka might work.  For the acid a mild vinegar.  In either case water to dilute to level of wine and match liquid volume.  Matching flavor without the fruit though will be tough.  Good results will probably depend on personal taste and the amount of wine the recipe called for and experimentation.